# ¿Cómo renombrar una imagen al subir la ruta en MySQL?

Tags: php7

He intentado con `uniqid()` para concatenarlo con el nombre de la imagen, pero no lo renombra al pasarlo a la carpeta donde se almacenan, tengo la intención de evitar errores de duplicidad.

```
$id = 0;
$name = '';
$location = '';
$ruta = '';

if (isset($_POST['save'])){ //el botón que tengo en el formulario tiene el nombre de 'save'
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    
    $nombre_imagen = $_FILES['ruta']['name'];
    $temporal = $_FILES['ruta']['tmp_name'];
    $carpeta='multidata';
    $ruta = $carpeta.'/'.$nombre_imagen;
    move_uploaded_file($temporal, $carpeta.'/'.$nombre_imagen);
    
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO data (name, location, ruta) VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$ruta')") or die($mysqli->error);
    
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Record has been saved!";
    $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "success";      
    
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

Estoy usando *Xampp Server*, en la siguiente ruta `htdocs/crud/multidata` es donde almaceno las imágenes, puesto que subir la ruta en la base de datos, ya lo hace, también muestra la imagen en el *index.php*. Intenté con `getRandomName()` pero este último no supe manipularlo.

Comment: Hola. No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿Qué nombre debe tener la imagen?

Comment: Un nombre con el que evite errores por duplicidad, o bien cómo implementar el `uniqid()` para la imagen que se guarda en el directorio local *multidata* porque puede guardar la ruta en la base de datos con el `uniqid()` pero no lo renombra al pasarlo a la carpeta.

Comment: Simplemente defines la variable así: `$ruta = $carpeta.'/'.$nombre_imagen.uniqid();` y estarás agregando al nombre de la imagen un Id único.

Comment: Probaré y te comento. Gracias.

Comment: @A.Cedano si añade el id único y guarda la ruta en la base de datos, pero en la carpeta local donde se guardan que es *multidata*, la imagen subida no se guarda junto el id único, ¿Cómo puedo añadirlo? Es decir, que la imagen pase a ser renombrado al nombre de la imagen junto el `uniqid()` en la carpeta local

Comment: Habiendo definido `$ruta` como te indiqué más arriba, pon esto así: `move_uploaded_file($temporal, $ruta);`

Comment: Gracias, he probado y guarda la imagen. También lo muestra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que agregar el valor obtenido con `uniqid()` al nombre de la imagen.

Por ejemplo:

```
$carpeta='multidata';
$ruta = sprintf("%s/%s_%s",$carpeta,$nombre_imagen,uniqid());
move_uploaded_file($temporal, $ruta);

$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO data (name, location, ruta) VALUES ('$name', '$location', '$ruta')") or die($mysqli->error);

// etc ...
```

### Advertencias sobre la seguridad

La subida de archivos al servidor es un aspecto muy delicado. Si no lo estás haciendo, deberías aplicar restricciones, como por ejemplo, limitar el tipo de archivo que se pueden subir, el tamaño, etc.  Supongamos que permites subir archivos con extensión `.php`, eso sería un gravísimo agujero de seguridad, porque un usuario mal intencionado puede subir cualquier script `.php` el cual se ejecutará sin ningún problema, causando todo el daño que el hacker haya programado en él. [Revisa las notas del Manual de PHP al respecto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Tu consulta SQL también es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Deberías usar consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese riesgo. Mediante *inyección SQL* el daño que se puede hacer en un servidor también es incalculable.